# How to combine day with string (text) in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to combine a day with a string that says "this is the day" in html.

I tried this, it does not concatenate right.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also, why would you hard-code the days if JS can provide that in each locale?

Comment: In what way does it not concatenate right?  Looks fine.  In your code screenshot, you don't even have "this is the day".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's better to use innerText if you don't insert html in your tag

moreover to get the weekday you can avoid stored weekday in an array and directly get it from data object

```
d.toLocaleString('en-us', {  weekday: 'long' })
```

```js
const weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]; 
const d = new Date(); 
let day = weekday[d.getDay()];
let dayFromdate =  d.toLocaleString('en-us', {  weekday: 'long' });
document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "This is the day, "+ day; 
document.getElementById("demo2").innerText = "This is the day, "+ dayFromdate;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="demo2"></div>
```